# C言語のqsortと独自実装でソートしたい

Tags: c

c言語についての質問です。

- 前提条件
  1～9の数字がランダムに記載されたテキストファイル before_sort.txt を手入力で作成する

  - 例）
    1
    3
    5
    7
    9
    2
    4
    6
    8
- 1: 作成した before_sort.txt をプログラムで読み込む
- 2: コマンドラインからパラメータを受け取り、数字を昇順/降順に並べ替える

  - 例） a を入力
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
  - 例） d を入力
    9
    8
    7
    6
    5
    4
    3
    2
    1

★ポイント 並べ替えの実装方法は qsort()関数 とループによる独自実装があるが、両パターンで作ること

上記の問題に対して、テキストファイルの文字の中身の配列を出力する所までは出来たのですが、その後の並び替えが出来ない状態で、どなたか教えて頂けないでしょうか？

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int i, n;
    int sin[9];
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("before_sort.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &(sin[i]));
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", sin[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 検索するとこんな記事が色々と見つかるので良さそうと思われるものを参考にしてみてください。[【C言語】qsort関数の使い方](https://daeudaeu.com/c-qsort/), [配列に格納した数値を昇順ソート](https://webkaru.net/clang/array-sort-ascending-order/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。